# XML-RPC Custom Hooks Request

Tags: 7, hooks

I have developed my own xmlrpc hook, which have certain functions.

Basically I need to call that functions outside Drupal. So I can't use xmlrpc() function.

What is most simple method to call that functions through Drupal's xmlrpc.php?

Comment: What language? What plattform? You might want to consider asking this on stackoverflow.com as it doesn't have much to do with Drupal really. You might get a better answer there, especially if it's not even PHP on the client side.

Comment: This is not a question about Drupal; it's a question about calling a XML-RPC function implemented in Drupal from outside Drupal, which is not different from calling a XML-RPC function implemented with Ruby from code written using a different programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has [an extension for XML-RPC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlrpc.php), but it's not enabled by default. If your PHP installation doesn't have the extension, you can use one of the PHP libraries that handle XML-RPC requests, such as [XML-RPC for PHP](http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/), and [The Incutio XML-RPC Library for PHP](http://scripts.incutio.com/xmlrpc/); if you have downloaded the Zend Framework, you can use [its XML-RPC classes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.xmlrpc.html).

Answer (score 0):

Without having more information (see my comment), the only advice I can give you is: Use an XML-RPC library for your language/plattform. Whatever language you are using, it is very likely that a library (or many) exists for it.

Comment: Language is PHP. At this moment I just need to test that functions.